# Facebook API to get access token

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a requirement where I want to use Facebookaccess token using only APIs.
I have seen methods which works using web requests and responses to get the Facebook API and they also use redirect URIs.

But I cant really use redirect URI since I want to use it in a azure worker role.

Something like:

```
facebook a=new facebook();
a.appid="";
```

This is just a visualization but any help would be great.

EDIT:

Below answer helps.
and if i use following uri in browser
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=app_Id&client_secret=secret_key&grant_type=client_credentials

it shows access_token=###
but if use following code to do the same in .net
    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=app_id
&client_secret=secretKey
&grant_type=client_credentials";

```
string token;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

it throws unauthorized

Comment: Please make an effort to write with proper punctuation - that makes a question easier to understand.

Comment: what exactly you would like to know? i want to get access token and post to fb fan page in azure worker role. where i cant use normal request response model to get access token as it requires redirect uri which does not exist for my requirement.

Comment: At some point your user has to accept your app, for obvious reasons.

Comment: i want to post as a part of batch schedulling so only admin can post to the wall at specific intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the C# API doesn't provide method for it, you can do it yourself. The access token is the content of following url. You just have to make https request.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

OK, so here is working PHP code:

```
function getAccessToken(){
    $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&grant_type=client_credentials';
    return makeRequest($token_url);
}

function makeRequest( $url, $timeout = 5 ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHP_APP" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if($response['http_code'] == 200) return $content;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: this method requires creating url and redirecting it then logging into facebook nd then u get access token.. i cant do that.

Comment: it does not require logging into facebook nor it requires redirects. I am successfully using it from PHP using CURL

Comment: it gives me unauthorized.i assume from your code,client_Id is app id and client secret is secret key of fb application.

Comment: client_id is name o paramter. You only need to set your APP_ID and your APP_SECRET. You can get those by creating an FaceBook app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: any idea if i want to post to specific fan page of which i am admin. do i need to add additional parameters to url?

Comment: sorry, I haven't ever deal with fan pages. And in this context, make sure which type of access token you require. If you require user access token (which is not the one, you can get by this method), or application access token.